# In Angular Update in Component's Constructor in service.subscribe doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular5

I have two component,parent and child and using shared service to send data between them.

Service Classs looks like this:

```
export class AddItemDataTransferService {

  // Observable string sources
  private childData= new Subject<string>();
  private parentData= new Subject<string>();


  // Observable string streams
  childdata$ = this.childData.asObservable();
  parentdata$ = this.parentData.asObservable();

   // Service message commands
addChildData(ch: string) {
  this.childData.next(ch);
 }

 addParentData(ch: string) {
  this.parentData.next(ch);
  }

  }
```

With tutorials from angular documentation,I did some things and sending data between the components works perfectly.

Lets look how child component looks:

```
export class AddItemSuccesResultComponent implements OnInit {
  newString = "This Should be changed";

 constructor(private getDataService: AddItemDataTransferService) { 

 getDataService.parentdata$.subscribe(
  ch=> {
              alert(ch);        
           this.newString = ch;

      });
   }
  }
```

Getting data works perfectly here.in browser alert is called and pop up window  shows the "ch" string.So it means,that data is imported from the service,but this.newString doesn't update.

The same case works when I'm importing data in parent view from child.but when I want to do the same in child component,it fails

Comment: Have you tried it with `console.log('ch: ', ch);` instead of `alert` ? Also i thinks that it's better to subscribe in ngOnInit() instead of constructor.

Comment: what is the difference? why it's important? the result is same, ch is logged in console,but object is not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your class `AddItemDataTransferService` You should change your `Subjects` to `BehaviorSubjects`. I'm assuming your child components subscribe to the exposed observables on your service *after* you've `addParentData` or `addChildData`.

Since you are using `Subjects` once you added data to them they will only broadcast to the current subscribers. Any subsequent subscribers will not get the previously broadcasted data.

By using a `BehaviorSubject` any subsequent subscribers will get the previously broadcasted data.

```
export class AddItemDataTransferService {

  // BehaviorSubjects must have a starting value. 
  private childData= new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  private parentData= new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
```

Comment: yeaah,good point.Changing to BehaviorSubject from Subject works perfectly,Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the code to ngOnInit.  Be careful on the logic that you put in your constructor because may depend on that is not available yet. Data is not always immediately available in the constructor, so it should do no more than set the initial local variables to simple values. The ngOnInit is a good place for a component to fetch its initial data;

Comment: I moved the method to ngOnInit, but nothing changed.alert works with data of string,but the newString is not updated :( while it works properly when getting data from child to parent and updating it

Comment: Another thing to check is to make sure your getDataService is only included in the providers in app.module,   not include it in the providers of  multiple components; otherwise it will have multiple instances of the service, which may mess up the subscription.